# When topological editing how can I automatically snap lines to lines close to them?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, topology

Using ArcMap 10.3, advanced license, I have a data set of road lines and another data set of road surface conditions, and I need to apply the road conditions to the road line as an attribute where it overlaps.  The problem is the lines do not overlap.

I have built a topology for it and have it identifying where one line does not get covered by the other line, but unfortunately that is most of the town.  I would therefore like to use automatic error correction and be able to go through the roads and let ArcMap do the spatial adjustment to align the conditions to where the road center line is.  I gave the center line a topology importance on 1 so it would not move and the road condition 5 so it would move.

However, when adding the topology and verifying it, then I choose the error correction tool and right-click on the error in the list, or on the error line, but I do not have a "fix error" type option.  Where do I find the trigger to have ArcMap move the one line onto the other?

I have also tried to use the Integrate geoprocess but it keeps failing with little info as to why.  I did remove the data from the topology before trying that.

Picture of data is below.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [Snap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/snap.htm) geoprocessing tool in the Editing Toolbox?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem without using typology. Take your Labrador drive red line road condition, if you snapped it to the underlying road it would in fact be intersecting Labrador and Neptune way at the junction, so which line do you pass your attribution to?

Try extracting the centroid of your surface line and then using Spatial join, joining the point  to the polyline dataset, This would create a new dataset of lines with attribution from both datasets. You would need to experiment on search distance and check for lines that were further than your specified distance.

For Neptune way you would only attribute the middle section, so in reality you will want to get the centroid of each road segment and spatially join that to your road surface. You could then join back the information to your road network using the transferred ID's

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Advanced license then you must use the [Detect Feature Changes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/detect-feature-changes.htm) tool.  It is the perfect tool specifically designed for comparing line networks as part of a conflation workflow.  It does a much better job than the spatial join tool could ever do, because it not only considers proximity, it also considers the overall bearing of each line and optionally detects matching attributes like street names.  You should use the option to create a match table to be able to relate one feature set to the other and understand whether or not the lines have a one-to-one relationship or a more complex relationship that may require you to merge or split lines.  That table can be used to create joins for transferring attribute data between the two networks.